# Should I use == or === for ... if ($POST["var_name"] == 'my_string') then continue

Tags: php

I have the following code working .. but I want to make sure that I don't get false positives ... since PHP is funny when doing boolean ... I want to account for it some how.

```
$response = $_POST["response"];

if ($response == '00' || $response == '105'){  //do sth. }
```

Should I change my if block to:

```
if ($response === '00' || $response === '105'){  //do sth. }
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between `==`and `===`? Is the value of `$response` a string or integer?

Comment: Good question? It should be a string for its purpose ...code returned by third party site ..should I use sth like is_numeric to make sure?

Comment: I will end up using sth like : 

if ($response == '00' || $response === '105'){ //do sth. }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To visualize it with your example:

```
<?php

var_dump('00' == '00');        // bool(true)
var_dump('00' == '0');         // bool(true)
var_dump('00' == '000000');    // bool(true)
var_dump('105' == '105');      // bool(true)
var_dump('105' == '105.000');  // bool(true)
var_dump('105' == '0x69');     // bool(true)
var_dump('105' == '0105');     // bool(true)

var_dump('00' === '00');       // bool(true)
var_dump('00' === '0');        // bool(false)
var_dump('00' === '000000');   // bool(false)
var_dump('105' === '105');     // bool(true)
var_dump('105' === '105.000'); // bool(false)
var_dump('105' === '0x69');    // bool(false)
var_dump('105' === '0105');    // bool(false)

?>
```

Comment: In addition to fix this I would use [type juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) it to int or float depending on your needs

Answer (score 5):

From http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/php-questions/difference-between-and-in-php/

> The == operator just checks to see if the left and right values are
>   equal. But, the === operator (note the extra “=”) actually checks to
>   see if the left and right values are equal, and also checks to see if
>   they are of the same variable type (like whether they are both
>   booleans, ints, etc.).

So you should use `===` if you also needs to check the variable type too..

Comment: Which in this case, you really won't.  Based on that link (good link, btw) you really only need to worry about your comparison returning `0`, which could be interpreted as `false`.  In this case, you're not using a function which could return `false`, and you're comparing strings which couldn't be confused with `0`, so you should be OK with just `==`.

Comment: That's a really good link! For my pupose I only need to worry about three possible values 0, 00 and 105. So I think I will end up using sth like : if ($response == '00' || $response === '105'). With == for checking for 0 and === for checking for 105.

Answer (score 2):

From php docs, you only need === if you want it to check type in addition to value.

```
$a == $b    Equal       TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.
$a === $b   Identical   TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.
```

Source: [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `===` when you want a comparison not only on the value of the variable, but also on the type. Therefore I'd say you should definitely use `===` in this case.

As a descriptive example, `1 == true` is true, but `1 === true` is false.